# Counting tables Length inside a body element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a page which is coming as:

```
<html<head></head><body><table><tr><td><table><table></td></tr></table><table></table><table></table></body></html>
```

Now the above page has 3 tables, i am trying to count the tables inside a body element, i am using the length to count, but it is giving me invalid results

```
alert($('#data').find("table").length);
if ($('#data').find("table").length <= 2) {
    $('#data').find("table:first").remove();
$('#data').find("table:last").remove();
}
```

it gives me 85, which is wrong, what is the correct way of getting this:

Comment: a) your opening html element isn't formed properly. b) where's the element with the ID of data?

Comment: are you just trying to get the # of tables or cells etc.?

Comment: this is the html which is loaded inside a container tag

Comment: You can't have a `<html>` inside another.

Comment: i can't but it is being loaded from external site with jquery, i know its invalid but somehow it is working now {through jquery, the data inside body is only shown, else other stuff has ben removed}

Comment: Why are you only removing the first and last table if there are only 2 or less tables?

Comment: there are minimum of 3 tables, i want to remove 1st and last table, even if there are 10 tables, i want to remove 1st and last only, but minimum of 3 are there

Comment: Reread my comment and your if statement, 'if ($('#data').find("table").length <= 2) { /* removes first and last */ }'

Comment: so u saying my condition is wrong,

Comment: If I understand correctly the test should be `num >= 5` that way you will always have three tables after removing the first and last, or `num >= 3` if you want to act on tables numbering more than 3.

Comment: if there are 3 tables only, i want to remove first and last and keep with one, that is the last condition, the tables if shows 10 tables, still it will remove first and last because they are kind ofheader and footer which we need not require

Answer (score 0):

See the Example below and adjust as need.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var n = $( "table" ).length;
 
  $( ".table-count" ).text( "There were  " + n + " Tables but the first and last are hidden"); 
  // kill the line above if you don't want the count output
  
  if($('table').length >= 3 ) { 
  // The above says; if there 3 or more tables, execute the line below
         $('table:first,table:last').hide();  
 }    
});
```

```css
table {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  }

.table-count {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table></table> 
<table></table> 
<table></table>




<div class="table-count"></div><!-- End Table COunt -->
```

**Note** forom your explanation; I don't think the **if** condition is necessary, you can just do something like below alone and the first and last will always be hidden.

```
$('table:first,table:last').hide(); // Adjust as needed
```

Answer (score -1):

This will get the number of tables in the body.

```
var numTables = $('body table').length;
alert(numTables);
```

**Edit:** To get all the tables within a certain element change the body selector to the appropriate class or id etc. selector.

Comment: I gotta ask why the -1? 'i am trying to count the tables inside a body element'

Comment: I didn't downvote (first), but this will count all tables in the document; not in the specific `div` loaded with external content, as in the question. You're not addressing the problem the OP is seeing.

Comment: I was addressing word for word the question. As quoted in the first comment. However I will edit.

Comment: See the later comment "...it is being loaded from external site with jquery..." and the sample code.